# TinyMCE triggerSave() command - is there a performance penalty?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, tinymce

It appears that in order to make TinyMCE work with an ASP.NET AJAX website, inside an `UpdatePanel`, that you must call something like this to cause TinyMCE to "save" the contents of the TinyMCE editors into the actual TextArea elements in the DOM.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this, GetType(), "TinyMCEAsynchCompatibility", "tinyMCE.triggerSave();");
```

**My question is**, will there be a performance penalty if I put this on all my pages, even those that don't use `UpdatePanels`?  Or does TinyMCE do this on every submit anyway?

If there is a penalty, anyone know what it is?  I ran the JavaScript on the Chrome Profiler and, best I can tell, it takes about .19% of the total time to submit (which is nothing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that there is a big performance penaylty.

The only issue that could arise is that if you got more than one editor on your page but need to write back the content of one single editor only, a simple `my_editor.save()` does the job.
`triggerSave()` will trigger `save()` for all editor instance which is not necessary in this case - and of course takes some more time (but usually not that much at all).